# Web Api not returning error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

POST action is returning 400 bad error. However, it's not returning the error message. I am overriding OnActionExecuting method on ActionFilterAttribute class and I do see ModelState populated and validation errors are also visible in watch, please see the snap,

[image]

I have POST action implemented like this. Its simply returning updated object from the database.

```
[HttpPost]
[ODataRoute()]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]ComponentDTO baseComponent)
{
    Component component = _mapper.Map<Component>(baseComponent);

    var result = await _repo.AddDocumentIntoCollectionAsync(component);
    return Created(result);
}
```

Any idea, what I maybe doing wrong?

Comment: What is your expected result?  That the API return 400 Bad Request with the validation result in the response content?

Comment: Screenshot shows the error that is not being returned

Comment: Perhaps related? https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7214

Comment: You are missing some code-flow here, but from what I can see you are getting a BadRequest and allowing it to pass all the way back up through your controller's Post method and back to the UI without ever addressing the validity of the result.  And given the error you're receiving on your UI vs the error contained in the message property of the result, you aren't doing any validation on the front end either.  I would strongly recommend, validating and handling before returning the value to the UI.

Comment: Or it could be that the method you have your break point in and see the error message is of return type void, and you aren't actually putting the error result in front of any code that does validation.

Comment: Any change if you call `base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext)` at the end of your filter?

Comment: Try returning a `JsonResult` instead with `Status` set to `BadRequest`.